# Why does my directly created SVG show up, yet my identical dynamically created SVG does not show up below it?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am wanting to move into dynamically creating SVG elements.

I have the following HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<script>
var d=document,ns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
window.onload = S;

function S() {
var bo=d.body;
var div=C(bo,'div');
A(div,'style','width:50vw;height:50vw;');
div.innerHTML="The second (dynamically created) svg does not show up!:"
var svg=Cn(div,'svg');
A(svg,'xmlns','http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');//An(...) gives error if used
An(svg,'viewbox','0 0 22 22');
An(svg,'style','width:40vw;height:40vw;');
var path=Cn(svg,'path');
An(path,'stroke','grey');
An(path,'d','M2 16c-4-2,0-10,4-8c3-12,24 8,12 8z');
}

function C(x,y){var z=d.createElement(y);x.appendChild(z);return z;}
function Cn(x,y){var z=d.createElementNS(ns,y);x.appendChild(z);return z;}
function A(x,y,z){x.setAttribute(y,z);}
function An(x,y,z){x.setAttributeNS(ns,y,z);}

</script></head>
<body>
<div style="width:50vw;height:50vw;">
The first svg here shows correctly:
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 22 22" style="width:40vw;height:40vw;">
<path stroke="grey" d="M2 16c-4-2,0-10,4-8c3-12,24 8,12 8z"></path></svg></div>
</html>
```

This is a real puzzle because the DOM elements for BOTH SVGs are showing up as IDENTICAL in dev tools:
[image: Dev tools]
I've tried numerous combinations of with/without SVG namespace, and other things for days and can't solve it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `An(svg,'viewbox','0 0 22 22');` you're setting `viewbox` instead of `viewBox` and while the browser will correct this for you on inline SVGs you provide (you can see this in your dev tools screenshot) it will not correct it on a dynamically created element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly set the namespace for the attributes, and you had a typo in `viewBox`:

```js
var d = document,
  ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
window.onload = S;

function S() {
  var bo = d.body;
  var div = C(bo, 'div');
  A(div, 'style', 'width:50vw;height:50vw;');
  div.innerHTML = "The second svg does too!:"
  var svg = Cn(div, 'svg');
  A(svg, 'xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
  A(svg, 'viewBox', '0 0 22 22');
  A(svg, 'style', 'width:40vw;height:40vw;');
  var path = Cn(svg, 'path');
  A(path, 'stroke', 'grey');
  A(path, 'd', 'M2 16c-4-2,0-10,4-8c3-12,24 8,12 8z');
}

function C(x, y) {
  var z = d.createElement(y);
  x.appendChild(z);
  return z;
}

function Cn(x, y) {
  var z = d.createElementNS(ns, y);
  x.appendChild(z);
  return z;
}

function A(x, y, z) {
  x.setAttribute(y, z);
}

function An(x, y, z) {
  x.setAttributeNS(ns, y, z);
}
```

```html
<div style="width:50vw;height:50vw;">
  The first svg here shows correctly:
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 22 22" style="width:40vw;height:40vw;">
    <path stroke="grey" d="M2 16c-4-2,0-10,4-8c3-12,24 8,12 8z"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```